# Check element value of specific element in list

Tags: python, list, loops, class

I'm working on an assignment covering classes. There are several requirements but my program meets nearly all of them the way it is currently.
The program is to prompt the user to enter either a car or truck into their virtual garage. From there they select a number of options depending on if it is a car or truck.
The user continues doing this until they are done adding vehicles, then they get prompted with the vehicles they entered and their info.
As it is currently, I can enter an endless amount of cars or trucks and it will print what I entered correctly. It will not allow me to enter in both cars and trucks, which is what I need it to do.
I know the issue is likely with my last loop since it references carTruck and it should probably reference the value of the element in the instances list. I am unsure how to do that though.

I realize there are probably better ways to achieve this but there are certain ways it must be done according to the assignment. Also, error handling isn't needed in this so that is why it is not included.

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, make, model, color, fuelType,options):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.fuelType = fuelType
        self.options = options
            
    def getMake(self):
        self.make = input('Please enter the vehicle make: ').title()
        return self.make
        
    def getModel(self):
        self.model = input('Please enter the vehicle model: ').title()
        return self.model

    def getColor(self):
        self.color = input('Please enter the vehicle color: ')
        return self.color

    def getFuelType(self):
        self.fuelType = input('Please enter the vehicle fuel type: ')
        return self.fuelType

    def getOptions(self):
        optionslist = []
        print('\nEnter Y or N for the following options')
        radio = input('Does your vehicle have a radio: ').lower()
        bluetooth = input('Does your vehicle have bluetooth: ').lower()
        cruise = input('Does your vehicle have cruise control: ').lower()
        window = input('Does your vehicle have power windows: ').lower()
        lock = input('Does your vehicle have power locks: ').lower()
        mirror = input('Does your vehicle have power mirrors: ').lower()
        rstart = input('Does your vehicle have remote start: ').lower()
        bcamera = input('Does your vehicle have a back up camera: ').lower()

        if radio == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Radio')
        if bluetooth == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Bluetooth')
        if cruise == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Cruise Control')
        if window == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Power Windows')
        if lock == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Power Locks')
        if mirror == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Power Mirrors')
        if rstart == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Remote Start')
        if bcamera == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Backup Camera')

        self.options = optionslist    
        return self.options

#car child class        
class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__ (self, make, model, color, fuelType,options, engineSize, numDoors):
        self.engineSize = engineSize
        self.numDoors = numDoors
        Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, color, fuelType,options)

    def getEngineSize(self):
        self.engineSize = input('Please enter your engine size in liters: ')
        return self.engineSize

    def getNumDoors(self):
        self.numDoors = input('Please enter the number of doors: ')
        return self.numDoors    

#pickup child class
class Pickup(Vehicle):
    def __init__ (self, make, model, color, fuelType,options, cabStyle, bedLength):
        self.cabStyle = cabStyle
        self.numDoors = bedLength
        Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, color, fuelType, options)

    def getCabStyle(self):
        self.cabStyle = input('Please enter the cab style: ')
        return self.cabStyle

    def getBedLength(self):
        self.bedLength = input('Please enter the bed length: ')
        return self.bedLength   


#creates instance and loops to get info for vehicles from user
instances = []
Exit = 'n'
x = 0
while Exit == 'n':
    carTruck = input('Are you entering a car or truck? ')
    plateNum = input('please enter your license plate number: ')
    instances.append(carTruck + plateNum)

#if statement to use correct class based on user input
    if carTruck == 'car':

        instances[x] = Car('','','','','','','')

        instances[x].getMake()
        instances[x].getModel()
        instances[x].getColor()
        instances[x].getFuelType()
        instances[x].getEngineSize()
        instances[x].getNumDoors()
        instances[x].getOptions()
        if not instances[x].options:
            print('\nYou need to select at least one option.')
            Vehicle.getOptions(instances[x])
        
    elif carTruck == 'truck':
        instances[x] = Pickup('','','','','','','')

        instances[x].getMake()
        instances[x].getModel()
        instances[x].getColor()
        instances[x].getFuelType()
        instances[x].getCabStyle()
        instances[x].getBedLength()
        instances[x].getOptions()
        if not instances[x].options:
            print('\nYou need to select at least one option.')
            Vehicle.getOptions(instances[x])
    
    #allows user to stop adding vehicles
    Exit = input('Are you done adding vehicles (Y/N): ').lower()
    x = x + 1



#loops through instances and provides output dependent on whether it is a car or truck.
b = 0
while b < len(instances):
    if carTruck == 'truck':
        print(f'Your vehicle is a {instances[b].color} {instances[b].make} {instances[b].model} {instances[b].cabStyle} and a {instances[b].bedLength} ft bed that runs on {instances[b].fuelType}.')
        print(f'The options are ' + ", ".join(instances[b].options) +'.\n')
    elif carTruck == 'car':
        print(f'Your vehicle is a {instances[b].color} {instances[b].make} {instances[b].model} {instances[b].numDoors} door with a {instances[b].engineSize} liter {instances[b].fuelType} engine.')  
        print(f'The options are ' + ", ".join(instances[b].options) +'.\n')
    b = b + 1




Output:
Are you entering a car or truck? car
please enter your license plate number: 123456
Please enter the vehicle make: ford
Please enter the vehicle model: mustang
Please enter the vehicle color: red
Please enter the vehicle fuel type: gas
Please enter your engine size in liters: 5
Please enter the number of doors: 2

Enter Y or N for the following options
Does your vehicle have a radio: y     
Does your vehicle have bluetooth: y
Does your vehicle have cruise control: y
Does your vehicle have power windows: y
Does your vehicle have power locks: y
Does your vehicle have power mirrors: y
Does your vehicle have remote start: y
Does your vehicle have a back up camera: y
Are you done adding vehicles (Y/N): n
Are you entering a car or truck? truck
please enter your license plate number: 789456
Please enter the vehicle make: chevy
Please enter the vehicle model: 1500
Please enter the vehicle color: black
Please enter the vehicle fuel type: gas
Please enter the cab style: crew cab
Please enter the bed length: 6

Enter Y or N for the following options
Does your vehicle have a radio: y
Does your vehicle have bluetooth: y
Does your vehicle have cruise control: y
Does your vehicle have power windows: y
Does your vehicle have power locks: y
Does your vehicle have power mirrors: y
Does your vehicle have remote start: y
Does your vehicle have a back up camera: y
Are you done adding vehicles (Y/N): y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chris\Desktop\School\Intro to Programming\python_work\classes.py", line 138, in <module>
    print(f'Your vehicle is a {instances[b].color} {instances[b].make} {instances[b].model} {instances[b].cabStyle} and a {instances[b].bedLength} ft bed that runs on {instances[b].fuelType}.')
AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'cabStyle'
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you read the answer, ask yourself **where did you get** the *carTruck* instance you are trying to print.

...

You are referring to the last entry you have added instead of referring to the current instance! So correct way will be, eg.

```
b = 0
while b < len(instances):
    if isinstance(instances[b], Pickup): #CHANGED
        print(f'Your vehicle is a {instances[b].color} {instances[b].make} {instances[b].model} {instances[b].cabStyle} and a {instances[b].bedLength} ft bed that runs on {instances[b].fuelType}.')
        print(f'The options are ' + ", ".join(instances[b].options) +'.\n')
    elif isinstance(instances[b], Car): #CHANGED
        print(f'Your vehicle is a {instances[b].color} {instances[b].make} {instances[b].model} {instances[b].numDoors} door with a {instances[b].engineSize} liter {instances[b].fuelType} engine.')  
        print(f'The options are ' + ", ".join(instances[b].options) +'.\n')
    b = b + 1
```

I want to add two suggestions...

1st - don't use while loop here use for, eg.

```
for moving_thing in instances:
   if isinstance(moving_thing, Pickup):
       ...
```

2nd - create `__str__` method for each class so you could call it without checking what type of vehicle it is. More here [Dunder methods](https://builtin.com/data-science/dunder-methods-python), than you could call

```
for moving_thing in instances:
    print(moving_thing)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I could tell that the carTruck instance was the issue but couldn't figure out what I needed. isinstance is the function I needed to find.  Also, thank you for providing more insight. I have not heard of dunder methods and I will be looking into them.